Why do elliptic curve over finite field addition formulas not depend on the curve parameters?
Consider an Elliptic Curve $E:y^2 = x^3 +ax+b \mod p$
Points $P = (x_1, y_1)$ & $Q=(x_2,y_2)$
$s = \frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$
$x_3 = s^2 -x_1-x_2 \mod p$
$y_3 = s(x_1 - x_3) - y_1 \mod p$
I am a little confused as to how the addition formula doesn't depend on Curve Parameters $a$ & $b$
How is this possible considering 2 points do not define the curve. Considering these 2 points may also lie on a different elliptic curve will the addition of the 2 points result in the same result on the other curve also as long as the underlying field is the same?

The doubling formulate uses $a$.

Yes, fixed that in the question

N.b. not all curves can be written in Weierstrass short form in characterstic $2$ or $3$.

The fact that those two points lie on the curve leads to a pair of linear equations, and we can solve for $a$ and $b$ from them. Assuming $x_1\neq x_2$, the two equations will be linearly independent, meaning that the solution is unique. Of course, the case $x_1=x_2$ is special, and your parameter $s$ won't be an element of the field.
Summary: In this case two points do usually determine a unique elliptic curve.

So that means the same 2 points cannot lie on 2 different elliptic curves defined over the same underlying field?

Correct, unless they are symmetrically about the $x$-axis. Do observe that this only applies to curves in the short Weierstrass form. For more general ellipctic curves two points won't suffice.
